# Render Custom Component Inside NextJS Link

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-link

## Issue:

I have a component that should redirect users to a new page on click. I want to use Next's `<Link>` component to take care of the route change.

However, I've noticed that the `Link` component refuses to render if any of its children are not standard HTML elements (e.g., `<div>`, `<a>`, ...).

In the example below, the component I want to render is an icon from the `heroicons` library.

**MyPage.js**

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import { ArrowSmRightIcon } from 'heroicons-react'

export default function MyPage() {
    return(
        <Link href='/targetPage'>
            <ArrowSmRightIcon />
        </Link>
    )
}
```

Running the above renders the following error:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined.

---

## Attempted solution:

I've found some advice online about having to create a custom component that using `forwardRef`. I've implemented my custom component as:

**IconLink.js**

```
import NextLink from 'next/link'
import { forwardRef } from "react";
import { ArrowSmRightIcon } from 'heroicons-react'

const IconLink = forwardRef(({ href, prefetch, replace, scroll, shallow, locale, ...props }, ref) => {
    return(
        <NextLink
        href={href}
        replace={replace}
        scroll={scroll}
        shallow={shallow}
        locale={locale}
        passHref
        >
            <ArrowSmRightIcon ref={ref} {...props} />
        </NextLink>
    )
  })

export default IconLink
```

**MyPage.js**

import IconLink from './IconLink';

```
export default function MyPage() {
    return(
        <IconLink
            passHref
            href='/targetPage'
        />
    )
}
```

However, I still get the same error.

What should I do render a custom child component inside Next's `<Link>` component?

Comment: Also if you want users to right click and open the link in new tab, wrap your child component in an <a > tag. Along with passHref wich you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not from the next/link, the problem is from the import, This error indicates that there is no named export "ArrowSmRightIcon" in the package heroicons-react I believe what you're looking for is ArrowSmRight

```js
import { ArrowSmRight  } from 'heroicons-react'
```

Plus the package is deprecated as stated by the maintainers:

> This package has been deprecated
>
> Author message:
>
> Official Heroicons V1 released. Please use the following for future >
> projects: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@heroicons/react

the currently maintained version is:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@heroicons/react